# Access JSON serializer configured in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, json, testing, asp.net-core

I have an API controller that returns instance of a class *ExampleDataType*. The default behavior is that the object is serialized to JSON and that's fine.

**API controller snippet:**

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class ExampleController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ExampleDataType Get()
    {
        return new ExampleDataType();
    }
}
```

I would like to slightly change the way of object serialization (property casing). I configured JSON serializer built in ASP.NET Core application in following way:

**Startup.cs:**

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2)
            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.UseMemberCasing();
            });
    }
```

So far so good. Now, I would like to create a (unit?) test that would document intended behavior. My idea for such test is:

1. Access the JSON serializer with applied customizations in Server.
2. Use the serializer on a test class instance.
3. Assert the results.

I already know how to spawn a test, in-memory server instance with WebApplicationFactory. Alas, I don't know how to access the serializer configured in server.

Any ideas?

Comment: So do you want to test that Microsoft's code works? Or that you've configured it the way it should be? The way you test would be different. For the latter, you could mock the `AddJsonOptions` method and test that the function passed in sets the options appropriately...

Comment: This is testing the framework, which is a huge no-no. ASP.NET Core is already thoroughly tested. If you set it the JSON serializer to `UseMemberCasing`, then you can rest assured that it will. If you're wanting to test that the line to do set that has actually been included, then you simply hit an action that returns JSON and do a case-sensitive string compare to ensure that the members are cased appropriately.

Comment: A better way would be to do proper integration tests on your endpoints and verify that the properties are properly cased there. There is little use to unit testing a component that you don’t own and that is hidden deep inside the framework. You rather want to test that its desired effect applies.

Comment: @HereticMonkey - I would want to test (or rather: leave a safeguard for future) that casing is as I expect it now. Mocking the method would probably work, but there are two issues with it. First is that I would be testing implementation instead of visible behavior, that's something I always try to avoid. The second is that someone could call `AddJsonOption` multiple times and I would have to keep a track of a shape of `MvcJsonOptions` object between the calls to assert on its final form.

BTW., any ideas how mock an extension method?

Comment: @ChrisPratt, poke - I agree with you that trying to UNIT test one of the internals is a bad idea and integration test in this case seems to more most appealing. One major concern I have is that following ChrisPratt's suggestion would require me to rely on some specific action and its output. In case the output changes or action is deleted, I need to rewrite my test for json casing. Another contrived scenario would be that I don't really know what happens inside of this action: insane programmer could use JsonConvert by hand. I need to control (in test) fake action implementation. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, I will say the quest for 100% code coverage is folly. You want the most important parts of your codebase tested, and you may even get close to complete code coverage, but eventually you find yourself spending inordinate amounts of time trying to test rather insignificant things overall. That's pretty clealy the case here.

Comment: In most cases, JSON member casing doesn't even matter. The only time it might is if you're doing things client-side and relying on the JSON object that is returned explicitly. In that regard, coded UI tests will generate fail due to casing errors, and you'd be able to track down the issue from there. Long and short, your time is likely spent better elsewhere, and there's a high likelihood hood that other tests will actually end up covering this by nature.

Comment: _“insane programmer could use JsonConvert by hand”_ – Yes, and exactly that case isn’t verified by a test that verifies that you have configured a framework correctly. If you require certain endpoints to return output in a specific format, then you will need to test that endpoint, not some component in between that may or may not even be used for it. – Unless you are actually building a framework, you will want to test actual action/endpoint implementations.

Comment: @ChrisPratt, by no means I aim towards 100% code coverage. The issue I originally posted is just an example of a testable behavior that I have a trouble with covering and I hoped that maybe I am missing some simple mechanism that could help me reach the goal. The casing is indeed requirement for UI components that request for the data. But if I would test the UI components, I'd probably provide them with a stubbed, well-formed JSON.

Comment: @poke, I totally agree about the remark regarding tests for framework configuration. I would like to test default JSON formatting, that's why I don't like the idea of testing some random endpoint of application as I simple cannot be sure of its internals. I woud rather create test endpoint during test setup and assert its results.

Do you have any suggestions on how could I add test controller to server in tests?